# XSS via Ajax request?

Tags: web-application, web-browser, ajax

I'm currently honing in on my web exploitation skills and came across this JavaScript function here:

```
 Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    new Ajax.Request('/dir/dir', {
      method: 'post',
      parameters: 'action\x3DrefreshAjaxModule\x26amp\x3BmodId\x3D_1895_1\x26amp\x3BgroupId\x3D_1_1\x26amp\x3Bgroup_id\x3D\x26lt\x3BXSS',', 
      onSuccess: function(transport) {
        try {
          var res = transport.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('x')[0].textContent;
          $('div_1').innerHTML = res.stripScripts();
          page.globalEvalScripts(res,true);
        } catch (e) { 
          $('div_1').innerHTML = 'Failed';
        }
      },
      onFailure: function(transport) {
        $('div_1').innerHTML = 'Fail';
      }
    });
  });
```

My understanding of the script is that when the page loads, an Ajax POST request will be sent, and if it's successful, it'll call the function and try do something but I'm not entirely sure what it's doing...

I feel like this might be an attack vector, as you can inject values into the `parameters` field via the URL, except things like `<script>` are filtered and switched out with `<xxxx>`. `` <body onload`=alert(1)> `` seems to get through unfiltered, but it requires the back tick, which makes the alert not work.

I'm just wondering what other possible payloads there could potentially be, if any? When I inject `<XSS` (like in the code above) it falls through to the catch statement so I'm not sure if there's something I can do to make it not cause an exception and pass things through as valid input.

Comment: I'm not sure if I don't understand your question. But I cannot see how the attacker could even manipulate the URL or parameters in the Ajax request for a __page running inside the victims browser__. To do this the attacker would already need to exploit another XSS.

Comment: There's a parameter in the URL, i.e. ?id=x, where I made x = XSS in the example above. This passed it directly into the function: action\x3DrefreshAjaxModule\x26amp\x3BmodId\x3D_1895_1\x26amp\x3BgroupId\x3D_1_1\x26amp\x3Bgroup_id\x3D\x26lt\x3BXSS <-- injected part at the end here

Comment: Now I understand it a bit better. But what happens with this parameter? Does it get reflected back? Does it survive or does harm inside stripScripts and globalEvalScripts, whatever these functions do? Too much unknowns. Or is it put in plain into the `parameters` and you want to break out of the quotes? It is not really clear to me what you are trying to achieve.